# Rails 3.1, can't make link_to image_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, link-to

I want to make a fairly straightforward image link that uses an image from my assets. Getting weird errors. First I tried:

```
<%= link_to assets_path "town.png", 'index' %>
```

and got the error

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Nov 30 17:27:10 -0500 2011
Processing by PagesController#intro as HTML
Rendered pages/intro.html.erb within layouts/application (114.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 124ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `assets_path' for #<#<Class:0x10fdc4898>:0x10fdaad58>):
1: <body onload="init();">
2:  <div id = "wrapper2">
3:  <div class="intro_txt">
4:      <%= link_to assets_path "town.png", 'index' %>
5:      <br><br>
6:  </div>
7:  </div>
 app/views/pages/intro.html.erb:4:in     `_app_views_pages_intro_html_erb__1651075534_2280428740'
```

then I tried the old

```
<%= link_to image_tag "town.png", 'index' %>
```

and got this bizarre error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for "index":String):
1: <body onload="init();">
2:  <div id = "wrapper2">
3:  <div class="intro_txt">
4:      <%= link_to image_tag "townProjectText.png", 'index' %>
5:      <br><br>
6:  </div>
7:  </div>
app/views/pages/intro.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_pages_intro_html_erb__1651075534_2279838600'
```

What to do?

Comment: Some brackets might help. It might that Rails isn't able to understand the options you've provided. Perhaps something a bit more like: `<%= link_to(image_tag("town.png", :alt => 'Town Image'), index_url) %>`

Comment: @zoltarSpeaks post your comment as an answer. It looks good

Comment: @zoltarSpeaks Yup. post as answer so I can accept. I thought I had tried that... but I guess not. w/e. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= link_to image_tag('town.png'), 'index' %>
```

Put some parentheses

Answer (score 3):

You need some `()`

```
<%= link_to image_tag("town.png"), pages_path %>
```

Also, you need to use `image_tag`

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to image_tag("town.png"), image_path %>
```

if you want it to go to another page with the image by itself

Answer (score 0):

Yeah some brackets would perhaps help. Try something like this:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("town.png", :alt => 'Town Image'), index_url) %>
```