# How to link to a pdf from a png with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, link-to

I have an image of a map.png file on part of a page. I would like this image to be clickable, and then to download the pdf version of that image. I've been using this as a reference [Rails 3.1, can't make link_to image_path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333928/rails-3-1-cant-make-link-to-image-path), but I'm not sure how to proceed.

It looks like I also need to edit something with the way the page is routed. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a route to the pdf download or is the file itself a static asset?

You can use a standard `link_to` helper with an `image_tag` helper to create a clickable image.

**For a static pdf asset:**

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('my_image.png'), 'path/to/filename.pdf') %>
```

This will show the image `my_image.png` on the page which when clicked will begin downloading or displaying the static pdf asset.

**For a controller action that serves the file:**

Page:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('my_image.png'), download_pdf_path) %>
```

Controller:

```
def download_pdf
  send_file 'path/to/filename.pdf'
end
```

Route:

```
get 'download_pdf' => 'controller#download_pdf'
```

This will show the image `my_image.png` on the page which when clicked will make a get request to the pdf download action.